# Brave Browser has lines everywhere and is bugging out

Tags: graphics-card, browser, chromium, brave

So I'm not sure if it's just me but brave as well as vivaldi have been giving me these weird line issues whenever im using the browser, or unfocusing issues. not sure if it's the browsers or the graphics card.

I play games and use microsoft edge just fine.

I just got this new laptop and wanted to know what to do if I should replace it or if there is a fix.

Running Windows 10 Graphics card is a NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Laptop GPU Running latest brave version, I have a few extensions running but I had these on my older machine and never ran into an issue before.

[Example of lines and stuff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rGCH.png)
[Another screenshot from when I just posted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c2E4.jpg)

The picture above I had a youtube video playing and it kept going in and out.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your white box (image 2: 2c2E4.jpg) is not covered in lines, this would tell me, if it were my laptop, that only the window with lines is not active. Thus, the active window is alright... (no lines).